# Get an error trying to execute curl command from java code

Tags: java, curl

I have a trouble with executing curl command from java code. I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) construction to execute curl. Everything worked fine until I have been stuck on receiving response about 88kb. Executing of command is freezing. My code for executing command:

```
public String executeSimpleBash(String[] cmd) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Process p;
        String result;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            p.waitFor(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                result = output.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My command:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{
                "curl",
                "-H",
                "text/xml",
                "--insecure",
                "--max-time",
                "30",
                "-s",
                "-d",
                "languageSelect=enEn&xml=" + xmlBody,
                endpointUrl
        };
```

Comment: curl prints to standard error too.  That stream must be read or it will block.

Comment: I will suggest you use ProcessBuilder. it will let you check output/error in better way.

Comment: curl directly from command line executes the same command correct